# React Native: onPress triggering another onPress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native-base

I'm using the awesome `<Picker>` component from `Native Base`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {View, Picker, Text, Button, Icon} from 'native-base'

export default class PickSomething extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      SelectedValue: 'Foo',
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View >
        <Text>Type: </Text>

        <Picker
          iosHeader="Select a Type"
          selectedValue={this.state.SelectedValue}
          onValueChange={(value) => {
            this.setState(
              (prevState, props) => ({SelectedValue: value})
            )}}>

          <Picker.Item label="Foo" value="Foo" />

          <Picker.Item label="Bar" value="Bar" />
        </Picker>

        <Button
          onPress={ () => 
               //trigger the <Picker>onPress 
        }>
          <Icon name="ios-arrow-dropdown-circle-outline"/>
        </Button>
      </View>
    )}
}
```

I would like it to be more obvious that this is a dropdown. How do I make the `Button onPrees` trigger the onPress of the `Picker`?

Comment: but you didn't define the onPress on Picker ?? can u update ur ques with onPress code ?

Comment: the onPress behaviour is built into of the native-base component by default

Comment: Here's a solution: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7817#issuecomment-264837382

Answer (score 1):

On Android, You can set the prop `mode="dropdown"` to show a dropdown anchored to the picker view. That renders an arrow on the right side (check the [gif from the NativeBase docs](https://docs.nativebase.io/COMPONENTS.html#Picker)). iOS follows different design guidelines than Android so that prop won't work in iOS unfortunately.

NativeBase uses the react-native [Picker](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker.html) underneath the hood, but I don't see anything documented to imperatively open the picker from the outside using refs. You could always dig your way out into the src code, but it seems a measure of last resort.